# word2vec_basic output: trying to test word similarity versus human similarity scores

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

As a way to get familiar with Tensorflow, I am trying to verify that the word embeddings generated by `word2vec_basic.py` (see [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec)) make sense when checked against human similarity scores. However, the results are surprisingly disappointing. Here's what I do.

In `word2vec_basic.py`, I add another step at the very end to save the embeddings and the reverse dictionary to disk (so I don't have to regenerate them every time):

```
with open("embeddings", 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, final_embeddings)
with open("reverse_dictionary", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(reverse_dictionary, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

In my own word2vec_test.py, I load them and create a direct dictionary for lookups:

```
with open("embeddings", 'rb') as f:
    embeddings = np.load(f)
with open("reverse_dictionary", 'rb') as f:
    reverse_dictionary = pickle.load(f)
dictionary = dict(zip(reverse_dictionary.values(), reverse_dictionary.keys()))
```

I then define similarity as euclidean distance between the embedding vectors:

```
def distance(w1, w2):
    try:
        return np.linalg.norm(embeddings[dictionary[w1]] - embeddings[dictionary[w2]])
    except:
        return None # no such word in our dictionary
```

So far the results make sense, for example `distance('before', 'after')` is less then `distance('before', 'into')`.

Then, I downloaded human scores from http://alfonseca.org/pubs/ws353simrel.tar.gz (I borrowed the link and code below from Swivel project from "Model Zoo"). I compare the human scores for similarity and embedding distances as follows:

```
with open("wordsim353_sim_rel/wordsim_relatedness_goldstandard.txt", 'r') as lines:
  for line in lines:
    w1, w2, act = line.strip().split('\t')
    pred = distance(w1, w2)
    if pred is None:
      continue

    acts.append(float(act))
    preds.append(-pred)
```

I use `-pred` because the human scores increase with increased similarity, so the distance ordering needs to be inverted to match (smaller distances mean larger similarity).

Then I calculate correlation coefficient:

```
rho, _ = scipy.stats.spearmanr(acts, preds)
print(str(rho))
```

but it turns out very small, like 0.006. I retrained word2vec_basic with 4 words of context and vector length of 256, but it didn't improve at all. I then used cosine similarity instead of euclidean distance:

```
def distance(w1, w2):
    return scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(embeddings[dictionary[w1]], embeddings[dictionary[w2]])
```

Still no correlation.

So, what is it that I'm misunderstanding or doing wrong?

Comment: As a sanity check, compute the distance between a few well-known word pairs, e.g. `cat-dog` and `monday-tuesday`. If you did not lowercase your input, also try `Monday- Tuesday`. Try plotting the predicted and gold-standard similarities: `plt.scatter(acts, press)`

Comment: Yes, I did this, and the results look sane. At least they coincide with that word2vec_basic itself reports while training (it shows closest words to 16 selected words, every 10000 epochs, using cosine similarity). However, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: Yes, the results are dismal, but that's because the model is too small and is trained on too little data. As simple as that. [The implementation I experimented with](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) uses a corpus of 17M words and runs for 100K steps, and takes just 2 adjacent words of context for an embedding size of 128. I got a larger Wikipedia sample with 124M words, increased context to 24 words (12 on each side), embedding size to 256, and trained for 1.8M steps, and voila! The correlation (as measured in my question above) grew to 0.24.

I then implemented subsampling of frequent words as described [in this tutorial](http://mccormickml.com/2017/01/11/word2vec-tutorial-part-2-negative-sampling/) and correlation jumped further to 0.33. Finally I left my laptop overnight to train with 36 words of context and 3.2M steps, and it got all the way to 0.42! I think we can call this success.

So, to whoever is playing with it like me, looks like it's a game that takes lots of data, lots of patience, and NVidia hardware (which I don't have at the moment). But it's plenty of fun nevertheless.

Comment: I'm playing with the same thing, can you share your code?